# Can Bitbucket Pipelines run with windows docker files?

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

As the the title asks, can bitbucket pipelines run with windows dockers?

Some background - I've been doing some research on pipelines over bamboo. Many of the articles I've come across are while pipelines was still in beta and only supported linux docker files. I can't seem to find any information regarding whether pipelines will work with windows.

Bonus question! What are your opinions of bitbucket pipelines over bamboo deployment for a larger scale website?

Answer (score 4):

Currently bitbucket pipelines does not support windows docker files

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/limitations-of-bitbucket-pipelines-827106051.html

> Features not available for Pipelines yet
>
> - Jira integration.
> - Build statuses from Pipelines don't show up in the
>     development panel.
> - Build artifacts stored by Bitbucket (you can
>     still use third-party artifact repositories)
> - **Building Windows applications**
> - Accessing services like artifact repositories or container registries behind a firewall

Comment: Open feature request is here for anyone that wants to receive updates on when this is released: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13452/support-for-native-windows-net-builds-on

Answer (score -1):

[issue 13452](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13452/support-for-native-windows-net-builds-on) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139171/can-bitbucket-pipelines-run-with-windows-docker-files#comment90533326_50302246) by [phod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3262863/phod) now (May 2022) includes:

> I am happy to announce that windows runner is in GA now.

The BitBucket blog confirms:

> ### [Announcing support for Windows runners in Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/blog/windows-runners) (Leo Liang)
>
> We are happy to announce that Bitbucket Pipelines now supports self-hosted runners on Windows.
>
> You can create a self-hosted runner and run it on your Windows infrastructure to run builds with the .Net framework.
> Since you're using your own runner, you won’t be charged for any Bitbucket Pipelines build minutes.
>
> This self-hosted runner will be non-containerized, allowing your CI/CD step to access the host’s hardware, such as the graphics card or any connected external devices.
> Given that the runner will run directly on a Windows instance, we also don’t put restrictions on a step’s memory usage.
>
> #### Get Started
>
> To get started, go to your repository or workspace settings, and select the Runners tab in the left navigation menu.
> Select `Windows` from the dropdown and specify a runner name and any labels.
>
> Just as with other types of runners, if you choose to create a workspace runner, that runner can be used to run builds for any repository in that workspace.
>
> #### Configuring your `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml`
>
> To use your Windows runner in your Pipelines `.yaml` file, add a runs-on parameter with a windows label to a step, and that step will run on the next available Windows Runner that has all the required label(s).
> If all your Windows Runners are busy, then your step will be queued until one becomes available.
>
> ```yaml
> pipelines:
>  custom:
>    customPipelineWithRunner:
>      - step:
>          name: Step 1
>          runs-on: 
>            - 'windows'
>          script:
>            - echo "This step will run on a self hosted windows >infrastructure.";
>          caches:
>            - windows_bundler
> definitions:
>  caches:
>    windows_bundler: vendor/bundle
> ```
>
> To learn more about how to set up and use self-hosted runners on your own infrastructure, refer to our [support documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-runners-for-windows/) and watch the [runners demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ditUFbBZpts).
>
> Next up: In case you missed it, last month we announced that macOS runners are currently in beta and will be officially released soon.